# Accept (once only) policy page on login

Tags: redirect, login, cookies

I'm developing a simple application on WP that requires the user to accept a policy page on **first** login. If they accept, they're redirected somewhere (homepage), if not, they're redirected somewhere else (different page).

However, this "policy page" should only appear after login UNTIL the user accepts it, and after that it should never appear again.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Are there some plugins that would help? I tried playing around with "Redirection" plugin but it doesn't have an option to only show a page once. I assume it will have something to do with cookies.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say 'login' do you mean login as a normal WordPress user?  (Meaning they'll have an account in WordPress with a username and password?).  Or is this for anonymous visitors who need to accept a policy before viewing content?

Comment: Login implies credentials no?

Comment: Justine you could set a custom user meta to save a value if they had accepted your policy or not, but u cant retrieve that value until the user is logged in.

Comment: @JaredCobb – yes, I mean logging in as a WordPress user (using WP login form and redirect to the policy page instead of backend).